# Can't execute request to URL with self signed SSL certificate

Tags: python, soap, openssl, soap-client, zeep

I'm not able to do a request to this URL:
`https://cobranca.homologa.bb.com.br:7101/registrarBoleto` with self-signed SSL certificate.

I'm building an SDK to integrate with `Banco do Brasil`. BB is one of the biggest Banks in Brazil.

On the docs they give, they say to access this `URLs` and download the SSL certificate to use on requests.

- https://oauth.hm.bb.com.br/oauth/token
- https://cobranca.homologa.bb.com.br:7101/registrarBoleto

And the `WSDL` endpoint is:

- https://cobranca.homologa.bb.com.br:7101/Processos/Ws/RegistroCobrancaService.serviceagent?wsdl

I've downloaded all `SSL` certificates possible from those `URLs` and tried to execute this request

```py
from zeep import Client, Transport
from requests import Session

session = Session()
session.cert = "sdk_bancodobrasil/certificados/cobrancahomologabbcombr.pem"

transport = Transport(session=session)

cli = Client(
    'https://cobranca.homologa.bb.com.br:7101/Processos/Ws/RegistroCobrancaService.serviceagent?wsdl',
     transport=transport
)
```

I'm getting this error

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/client.py", line 62, in __init__
    wsdl, self.transport, settings=self.settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/wsdl.py", line 82, in __init__
    document = self._get_xml_document(location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/wsdl.py", line 143, in _get_xml_document
    location, self.transport, self.location, settings=self.settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/loader.py", line 74, in load_external
    content = transport.load(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/transports.py", line 110, in load
    content = self._load_remote_data(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/transports.py", line 126, in _load_remote_data
    response = self.session.get(url, timeout=self.load_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 344, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 335, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 436, in load_cert_chain
    self._ctx.use_privatekey_file(keyfile or certfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 995, in use_privatekey_file
    self._raise_passphrase_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 972, in _raise_passphrase_exception
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('PEM routines', 'PEM_read_bio', 'no start line'), ('SSL routines', 'SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file', 'PEM lib')]
```

I've tried with all certificates but with no success. Any help will be awesome.

Also, I did try few other `so` answers about use `SSL` certificate with `requests` but do not find anything usefull.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful in your case, but in a generic requests.get() you can pass verify=False as a parameter to allow the request to proceed despite the SSL error.

Comment: On this case, the server verify the certificate, but I`ll try anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

`requests` library by default check for trusted CA [certifi](https://certifiio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), if we add correct root certificate in `verify` param, it will pass the request.

Try to get Certificate Authority pem file from SSL certificate chain of domain https://cobranca.homologa.bb.com.br:7101/Processos/Ws/RegistroCobrancaService.serviceagent?wsdl.

and just change your code to use `session.verify` and pass CA pem file path.

```
session.verify = './sdk_bancodobrasil/certificados/AC_Banco_do_Brasil_v3_HOM.pem'
```